# MAking an element hidden in XSL FO

Tags: element, xsl-fo

I am trying to make on eofmmy elements in XSL FO hidden by using either XSLT, or FO attributes, but I am not sure what attribute to use.
I have tried **visibility**="hidden", and also **visible**="false" to no avail. Any profesionals know the correct attribute name to perform this function.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_visibility.asp) it should work. Could you post some of your xsl? Which fo processor are you using?